# Background image appear to be small in android app?

Tags: android, image, button, background

I have a little problem, if someone could tell why:
1. My background image in my toolbar's button appear really small ?
2. When I import some images, it show a blank image in the xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi thumbnails.

Screenshot:
[Android Studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGAdq.png)

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<Button>` is primarily meant to display text, though it does also allow you to display images. However, it allows you to display images above, below, to the left of, or to the right of the text. That is why you were able to get an image using `android:drawableTop`... this is the image to display *above* your text.

Probably you just want to use `<ImageView>` here instead, and specify your image using the `android:src` attribute.

Another solution would be to populate your toolbar using a menu instead of manually adding views, but perhaps that's not possible for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Button`, You can use `ImageButton` in this case and you can give android:src="[your icon]"

Note :

> Try to give min 48dp width and height to button